# Fill Array with object outside of it

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a query that returns a SKU with an array of Locations like this:

```js
[{
    "Locations": ["TP-401176509", [{
      "WarehouseCode": "01",
      "LocationCode": "A-04B01-B",
      "Quantity": 1,
      "Reserve": false
    }, {
      "WarehouseCode": "01",
      "LocationCode": "A-04B02-A",
      "Quantity": 1,
      "Reserve": false
    }, {
      "WarehouseCode": "01",
      "LocationCode": "A-04B13-A",
      "Quantity": 1,
      "Reserve": false
    }]]
  }

  OP is expecting to see this on output side: 
[{
    "Sku": "TP-401176509",
    "WarehouseCode": "01",
    "LocationCode": "A-04B01-B",
    "Quantity": 1,
    "Reserve": false
  }, {
    "Sku": "TP-401176509",
    "WarehouseCode": "01",
    "LocationCode": "A-04B02-A",
    "Quantity": 1,
    "Reserve": false
  }, {
    "Sku": "TP-401176509",
    "WarehouseCode": "01",
    "LocationCode": "A-04B13-A",
    "Quantity": 1,
    "Reserve": false
  }]
```

Essentially i want to map Locations[0] as a "Sku" object to fill the array in Locations[1]

Comment: Hey, Nick, it would help to answer you question if you could define your expected output structure. Can you manually define how you would like this to look and post it as part of the question?

Comment: [{     "Sku":  "TP-401176509",
      "WarehouseCode": "01",
      "LocationCode": "A-04B01-B",
      "Quantity": 1,
      "Reserve": false
    }, {"Sku":  "TP-401176509",
      "WarehouseCode": "01",
      "LocationCode": "A-04B02-A",
      "Quantity": 1,
      "Reserve": false
    }, { "Sku":  "TP-401176509",
      "WarehouseCode": "01",
      "LocationCode": "A-04B13-A",
      "Quantity": 1,
      "Reserve": false
    }]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `forEach()` loop to update each element of the array.

```js
const result = [{
  "Locations": ["TP-401176509", [{
    "WarehouseCode": "01",
    "LocationCode": "A-04B01-B",
    "Quantity": 1,
    "Reserve": false
  }, {
    "WarehouseCode": "01",
    "LocationCode": "A-04B02-A",
    "Quantity": 1,
    "Reserve": false
  }, {
    "WarehouseCode": "01",
    "LocationCode": "A-04B13-A",
    "Quantity": 1,
    "Reserve": false
  }]]
}];

result.forEach(res => {
    let sku = res.Locations[0];
    res.Locations[1].forEach(loc => loc.Sku = sku);
});
console.log(result);
```

Comment: The above solution worked and i was able to get the following with a bit of editing:

let arr = getInventoryLocations.data.map(x => x.Locations)

arr.forEach(res => {
  let sku = res[0]
  res[1].forEach(loc => loc.Sku =sku)
})
return _.flatten(arr.map(x=>x[1]))

It returned:

[{"WarehouseCode":"01","LocationCode":"A-04B01-B","Quantity":1,"Reserve":false,"Sku":"TP-401176509"},{"WarehouseCode":"01","LocationCode":"A-04B02-A","Quantity":1,"Reserve":false,"Sku":"TP-401176509"}]